# Vector iterator not incremental

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I'm trying to implement a  simple menu application in Qt and I got to the point where I have to make a filter button. Qt is giving an error and I don't know how to interpret it. It could come only from these 2 functions. I'll post a photo of the error as well.
Code for the filter operation:

```
vector<Car> Controller::filterByCategory(string category) {
    vector<Car> fin;
    vector<Car> all(repo->getAll());

    copy_if(all.begin(), all.end(),fin.begin(),
                [&](Car& cc) { return (cc.getCategory()==category); });
    return fin;
}
```

Qt function calling the filter function:

```
void OwnerWindow::filterCategory() {
    QString sCategory = lCategory->text();
    string category = sCategory.toStdString();
    vector<Car> cars = ctrl->getAllCars();
    vector<Car> fin;
    try {
        fin = ctrl->filterByCategory(category);
    }
    catch(WarehouseException& ex) {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Error!", QString::fromStdString(ex.getMsg()));
    }
    catch(...) {
        QMessageBox::information(this,"wtf",QString::fromStdString("huuuuuh"));
    }
```

Here my program crashes with the following error:
[image]

Any idea what could be happening, why Qt won't catch some error or why the code is not working?

EDIT:
I tried to count the number of elements i will add so I can create my final vector with a fixed size. Didn't work.

```
vector<Car> Controller::filterByCategory(string category) {
//    vector<Car> fin;
    vector<Car> all(repo->getAll());
    int i = 0;
    for_each(all.begin(),all.end(), [=](const Car& cc) mutable {
        if (cc.getCategory() == category) {
            i++;
        }
    });
    vector<Car> fin(i);
    copy_if(all.begin(), all.end(),fin.begin(),
                [&](Car& cc) { return (cc.getCategory()==category); });
    return fin;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `filterByCategory` is that the vector `fin` is *empty*, you either need to create it with the correct number of elements, or use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to create elements on demand.

By the way, there's no need to copy into the `all` vector first. Use e.g. `repo->getAll().begin()` directly in the `std::copy_if` call.

Comment: If he calls begin on a temporary, how will he get his end iterator?

Comment: Basically, it depends on if repo->getAll() returns a vector or a vector&. If it returns a vector&, then I agree with your answer. Otherwise, it's better to move construct it in "all"

Comment: I edited my post. I tried counting the elements so I could create fin with a fixed number of elements. Didnt work. Same error

Comment: @Charlotte45: Your code doesn't count the elements. Well, it does, technically. But it just throws away the result, because you capture `i` in your lambda by value. So after your call to `for_each`, `i` is still 0. Try `count_if`.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you! count_if + the fixed size was the solution, thank you all